# Flutter : ValueNotifier+ValueListenableBuilderとStateについて

Tags: flutter, dart

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/effects/photo-filter-carousel#interactive-example

I have a question about the sample at the end of the above page.

However, the question itself has little to do with the subject matter on the above page.

ExampleInstagramFilterSelection is a subclass of StatefulWidget.

State management seems to be done with ValueNotifier  + ValueListenableBuilder.

Looking at the code, I thought that ExampleInstagramFilterSelection could be a Stateless Widget, so I tried making it a Stateless Widget and tried it.
There is no particular error, and it looks exactly the same as before the change.

I can't think of the reason why ExampleInstagramFilterSelection is (a subclass of) StatefulWidget like the sample (why it's better to make it a subclass of StatefulWidget). Is there anything?

I can only think of "We might need State in the future", but then I feel like we should just make it a StatefulWidget when we need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, the `ExampleInstagramFilterSelection` in the above example could be simplified by converting it into a `StatelessWidget`.

As it is, there is no need to use a `StatefulWidget`, because the Widget does not need to redraw itself because of a changed member.
All the state handling is done in `FilterSelector`.